# Where is AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement in .NetStandard2.0?

Tags: c#, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I'm upgrading my class library from Net Framework 4.7.1 to NetStandard 2.0 and I have encountered a problem because I can't seem to find:

1. AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement
2. X509SecurityTokenParameters

I have added the following packages:

```
<PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.5.3" />
<PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Primitives" Version="4.5.3" />
<PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="4.5.3" />
```

What additional packages to I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [apisof.net](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.ServiceModel.Channels.AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement) reference, [AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.asymmetricsecuritybindingelement?view=netframework-4.7.2) is not available in .net standard 2.0, only full .net Framework and Mono.